# Kubernetes create secret and change default service account upon namespace creation

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

For reasons (namespaces are created every day) upon namespace creation I would need to do the following two actions:

- Add a gcr-json-key secret
- Add imagePullSecrets to the default ServiceAccount

Is there an automated way to do this in Kubernetes? Is there a template for the default Service Account created that I can change? (I am using Kubernetes 1.11.5 (AWS EKS))

Right now I don't have a very good way to deal with this problem...

Comment: How are the namespaces created ? If you're using Helm, you could very easily automate the above 2 tasks for every release. Every new release would create a new namespace (you get to configure that) and every release also creates the required secret and ServiceAccount.

Comment: It could be possible to create a custom controller / MutatingAdmissionWebhook to listen for namespace creation and then create needed resources from there. Otherwise, doing it through Helm / Kustomize / however your config is getting generated / applied might be the best answer

Comment: I will try using helm for my future deployments / namespace creations. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jason Stanley suggested:

> How are the namespaces created ? If you're using Helm, you could very
>   easily automate the above 2 tasks for every release. Every new release
>   would create a new namespace (you get to configure that) and every
>   release also creates the required secret and ServiceAccount.